# Uploading file in a Sharepoint Library with a required lookup field with copy.asmx

Tags: lookup-column, asmx, copy

I'm trying to upload a file in a document library. I'm doing it with the copy.asmx web service.

I've no problem with document libraries that don't contain lookup field.
But if the library includes a required lookup field it fails with no error message.
It shouldn't be a problem as Lookup fields are included in the service documentation.

[FieldInformation Type="Invalid or Integer or Text or Note or DateTime or Counter or Choice or Lookup...](https://www.customs.gov.sa/sites/sc/en/aboutsc/_vti_bin/copy.asmx?op=CopyIntoItems)

Here is my code

```
Copy copy = new Copy();

            copy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypassword", "mydomain");
            string destination = "http://url/mylibrary/";

            string file = "c:\\temp\myfile.txt";


            bool success = false;


            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

                string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string filenamenoext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            string destinationUrl = destination + filename;
                string[] destinationUrls = { destinationUrl };

                FieldInformation i1 = new FieldInformation { DisplayName = "Title", InternalName = "Title", Type = FieldType.Text, Value = filename };

            FieldInformation i3 = new FieldInformation { DisplayName = "MyLookupField", InternalName = "MyLookupField", Type = FieldType.Lookup, Value = "1;#Title1" };



            FieldInformation[] info = { i1 , i3 };


                byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                testwsclient.CopyIntoIntranetWebService.CopyResult myCopyResult1 = new testwsclient.CopyIntoIntranetWebService.CopyResult();
                testwsclient.CopyIntoIntranetWebService.CopyResult myCopyResult2 = new testwsclient.CopyIntoIntranetWebService.CopyResult();
                testwsclient.CopyIntoIntranetWebService.CopyResult[] myCopyResultArray = { myCopyResult1, myCopyResult2 };

                try
                        {
                            uint ret = copy.CopyIntoItems(filename, destinationUrls, info, data, out myCopyResultArray);



                        if (ret == 0)
                        {
                            int idx = 0;
                            foreach (testwsclient.CopyIntoIntranetWebService.CopyResult myCopyResult in myCopyResultArray)
                            {
                                string opString = (idx + 1).ToString();
                                if (myCopyResultArray[idx].ErrorMessage == null)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Copy operation " + opString +
                                        "completed.\r\n" + "Destination: " +
                                        myCopyResultArray[idx].DestinationUrl);
                            success = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                            Console.WriteLine("Copy operation " + opString +
                                        " failed.\r\n" + "Error: " +
                                        myCopyResultArray[idx].ErrorMessage + "\r\n" +
                                        "Code: " + myCopyResultArray[idx].ErrorCode);
                                }
                                idx++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        int idx = 0;
                        foreach (testwsclient.CopyIntoIntranetWebService.CopyResult myCopyResult in myCopyResultArray)
                        {
                            idx++;
                            if (myCopyResult.DestinationUrl == null)
                            {
                                string idxString = idx.ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine("Copy operation " + idxString + " failed.\r\n" + "Description: " + exc.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }

            Console.WriteLine("res" + success);
```